# rubyにおけるminitestが2回実行される

Tags: ruby

rubyでminitestを実行するとminitestが2回実行されてしまいます。
下記のようにシンプルなテストを実行しても、テストは成功するのですがminitestが2回実行されてしまいます。
何が問題でしょうか。
rubyのバージョンはruby 2.4.1です。

---

sample.rb

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class SampleTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_sample
    assert_equal 'test','test'
  end
end
```

---

実行結果

```
Run options: --seed 21334

# Running:

Run options: --seed 21334

# Running:

..

Finished in 0.004762s, 209.9958 runs/s, 209.9958 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips



Finished in 0.088777s, 11.2642 runs/s, 11.2642 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: どのように実行しているのかも書いたほうが回答がつきやすいように思います

Comment: 現象を再現できる最小限のコードと手順を質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 0, accepted):

横槍失礼致します。私の手元でも同じ現象が再現しました。
テストコードは以下の通りです。

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class FizzBuzzTest < Minitest::Test 
  def minitest_test
    assert false
  end
end
```

このソースを`ruby sample.rb`のように実行すると質問者様と同じ現象が発生しました。
minitestのバージョンは5.10.3および5.11.1で試し、両方で発生を確認しています。

#### コメント転記

少し調べたところ、railtiesがインストールされていると結果が2重に表示されるようです。gem uninstall railtiesでアンインストールすると改善しました。 – [Y_uuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/27132/y-uuu) 1月24日 11:16

一応issueを起こしておきました。 https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/740 – [Y_uuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/27132/y-uuu) 1月24日 11:17